# Make changes to the Radius of the default Circle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, measurement

How can I create a circle with a certain diameter/radius?
I know there's a way, but I don't know how to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps you can follow.

1. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on the keyboard.
2. Select Circle.
3. Hit <kbd>T</kbd> to activate the *Tool panel*.
4. Under the **"Add Circle"** Header, key in the radius of the circle you need.

[image]

**Note** Take care not to move the circle before you change it's radius the option would be unavailable if you moved the circle before hitting <kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: The operator properties are also available in a floating panel by pressing F6

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to create a circle with a designated radius is to add the circle mesh primitive. In the characteristics panel for the primitive, it allows you to specify the radius.